# How to check If a value exists in urlparse path

Tags: python, urlparse

So let's I ask a user for input like this:

```
url = input('enter URL: ')

parsed_url = urlparse(url).path

>>>>>>>>> /yellow/orange/blue
```

I only want to check to see if the first value in parsed_url, `'/yellow/'` exists or not. What would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: Maybe this will help you:

'yellow' == parsed_url.split('/')[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have something like `from urllib.parse import urlparse` (meaning that `parsed_url` is just a `str`), you can simply do

```py
if parsed_url.startswith('/yellow/'):
    print('Starts with /yellow/')
else:
    print('Does not start with /yellow/')
```

To be clear, `str.startswith()` will check if *the very first thing* in the path is `'/yellow/'`. If you want to allow cases like `' /yellow/...'` or `:/yellow/...` or whatever, the code has to be more involved.

Comment: Awesome! This gets the job done, I have other filters that are checking other values so this is good for now thanks! I was wondering, is there a way to limit the amount of values in a path? For example, I want the path to not have more than two values. If path has /yellow/oranges/blue, I want it to get rejected since the limit was only two values?

Comment: A simple (but somewhat error prone) solution is to just count the slashes: `parsed_url.count('/')`. This will of course treat `'/yellow'` differently from `'/yellow/'`, so perhaps `parsed_url.rstrip('/').count('/')` or even `parsed_url.strip('/').count('/')` is more suitable for you.